# Server 2012 R2 -- Using Storage spaces with hardware RAID?

Tags: windows, storage, software-raid, hardware-raid, storage-spaces

I'm studying for MCSA using Server 2012 R2. I'm running a Dell r610 rack server with a perc6/i controller for hardware raid. Hardware raid is set up with a virtual array in a RAID 10 configuration.

For learning purposes, can I go ahead and play around with Storage Spaces (which I understand is Server 2012 R2's software RAID solution) on top of the hardware RAID or do I have to disable and wipe out the Perc/6i hardware RAID for this to work? Beyond educational purposes, can software and hardware RAID be combined in general and what is the advantage of doing so?

I appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage spaces should not be implemented on top of a hardware raid.

That means:

- Using the hardware controller like a HBA without any raid configuration is fine, storage spaces must always have direct access to the physical disks without any additional layer of abstraction
- Setting up a raid on the hardware (like two mirrors) and setting up a storage pool upon the resulting raid-disks/luns is **not** supported

In your case: Dump the hardware raid configuration for the disks you want to use with storage spaces and setup any configuration within the storage spaces / virtual disks and so on.